# How to join tables in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, model-view-controller, mariadb

I have a tables `residence_staff` and `halls`. In the `residence_staff` table there is a field `position` and, if it is manager, I want to display a list of all the managers and the `hallName`, where they work in. I can print the names of managers just fine, but the application can not recognize `hallName`. The tables are joined using the `staffNumber` as a foreign key in the `halls` table, to `staffNumber` in the `residence_staff` table. What am I doing wrong?

`residence_staff` Model:

```
class ResidenceStaff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hall, primary_key: 'hallId'

  class << self

    def managers
      where(position: 'manager')
    end
  end
end
```

`halls` Model:

```
class Hall < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :residence_staffs
end
```

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @residence_staff = ResidenceStaff.all
    @residence_staff_managers = ResidenceStaff.managers.includes(:hall)
  end
end
```

View:

```
<h1>Title</h1>

<div>
  <% @residence_staff_managers.each do |residence_staff| %>
    <%= residence_staff.fName%>
    <%= residence_staff.hallName%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`Schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180426051412) do

  create_table "advisor", primary_key: "advisorNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.text "position", null: false
    t.text "deptName", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber", null: false
    t.index ["advisorNumber"], name: "Advisor_advisorNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "Advisor_email_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "hall_of_residences", primary_key: "hallName", id: :string, limit: 50, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.text "hall", null: false
    t.integer "staffNumber", null: false
    t.index ["hallName"], name: "HallOfResidence_hallName_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["staffNumber"], name: "HallOfResidence_ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "halls", primary_key: "hallId", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "hallName", null: false
    t.text "street", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "sfaffNumber", null: false
    t.index ["sfaffNumber"], name: "halls_residence_staffs_staffNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "invoice", primary_key: "invoiceNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "semester", limit: 50
    t.date "paymentDue"
    t.text "studentFName", null: false
    t.text "studentLName", null: false
    t.string "roomLocation", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "leaseNumber", null: false
    t.index ["invoiceNumber"], name: "Invoice_invoiceNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["leaseNumber"], name: "Invoice_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "invoice_payment", primary_key: "paymentID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.date "datePayed", null: false
    t.string "method", limit: 50, null: false
    t.date "dateOfFirstReminder"
    t.date "dateOfSecondReminder"
    t.integer "muNum", null: false
    t.index ["muNum"], name: "InvoicePayment_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["paymentID"], name: "InvoicePayment_paymentID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "lease", id: false, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "leaseNumber", null: false
    t.string "duration", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "studentFName", null: false
    t.text "studentLName", null: false
    t.integer "placeNumber", null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.date "dateToLeave", null: false
    t.date "dateToEnter", null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.index ["leaseNumber"], name: "Lease_leaseNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "Lease_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["placeNumber"], name: "Lease_placeNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "next_of_kin", primary_key: "nextID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.text "relationship", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "NextOfKin_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["nextID"], name: "NextOfKin_nextID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "parking_lot", primary_key: "lotNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "lotName", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "maxSpace", null: false
    t.integer "availability", null: false
    t.index ["lotNumber"], name: "ParkingLot_lotNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "residence_staffs", primary_key: "staffNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "homeCity", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postal", null: false
    t.date "dob", null: false
    t.text "gender"
    t.text "position", null: false
    t.string "location", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.integer "inspectedRoomID", null: false
    t.string "hall", limit: 50, null: false
    t.index ["inspectedRoomID"], name: "ResidenceStaff_StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_fk"
    t.index ["staffNumber"], name: "ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "room", primary_key: "placeNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "rentRate", limit: 50, null: false
    t.text "availability", null: false
    t.integer "roomNumber"
    t.string "hallName", limit: 50
    t.integer "apartmentNumber"
    t.index ["apartmentNumber"], name: "room_StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_fk"
    t.index ["hallName"], name: "room_HallOfResidence_hallName_fk"
  end

  create_table "staff", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "fName"
  end

  create_table "student", primary_key: "mUNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "fName", null: false
    t.text "lName", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 100, null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "phoneNumber", null: false
    t.string "email", limit: 100, null: false
    t.date "dob", null: false
    t.text "gender"
    t.text "standing", null: false
    t.text "nationality", null: false
    t.string "specialNeeds", limit: 100
    t.text "major", null: false
    t.string "statusOfStudent", limit: 100
    t.text "minor"
    t.text "comments"
    t.integer "advisorNumber", null: false
    t.index ["advisorNumber"], name: "Student_Advisor_advisorNumber_fk"
    t.index ["email"], name: "Student_email_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["mUNumber"], name: "Student_mUNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "student_apartment_inspection", primary_key: "inspectedRoomID", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.text "inspectorName", null: false
    t.date "dateOfInspection", null: false
    t.text "apartmentCondition", null: false
    t.text "comments"
    t.index ["inspectedRoomID"], name: "StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_uindex", unique: true
  end

  create_table "student_flats", primary_key: "apartmentNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "numberOfRooms", null: false
    t.text "city", null: false
    t.string "street", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "postcode", null: false
    t.integer "leaseID", null: false
    t.index ["apartmentNumber"], name: "StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["leaseID"], name: "StudentFlats_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  end

  create_table "vehicle", primary_key: "vNumber", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "plateNumber", limit: 10, null: false
    t.text "color", null: false
    t.text "manufacturer", null: false
    t.string "brand", limit: 50, null: false
    t.integer "mUNum", null: false
    t.integer "lotNumber", null: false
    t.index ["lotNumber"], name: "Vehicle_ParkingLot_lotNumber_fk"
    t.index ["mUNum"], name: "Vehicle_Student_mUNumber_fk"
    t.index ["plateNumber"], name: "Vehicle_plateNumber_uindex", unique: true
    t.index ["vNumber"], name: "Vehicle_vNumber_uindex", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "hall_of_residences", "residence_staffs", column: "staffNumber", primary_key: "staffNumber", name: "HallOfResidence_ResidenceStaff_staffNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "halls", "residence_staffs", column: "sfaffNumber", primary_key: "staffNumber", name: "halls_residence_staffs_staffNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "invoice", "lease", column: "leaseNumber", primary_key: "leaseNumber", name: "Invoice_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "invoice_payment", "student", column: "muNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "InvoicePayment_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "lease", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "Lease_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "next_of_kin", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "NextOfKin_Student_mUNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "residence_staffs", "student_apartment_inspection", column: "inspectedRoomID", primary_key: "inspectedRoomID", name: "ResidenceStaff_StudentApartmentInspection_inspectedRoomID_fk"
  add_foreign_key "room", "hall_of_residences", column: "hallName", primary_key: "hallName", name: "room_HallOfResidence_hallName_fk"
  add_foreign_key "room", "student_flats", column: "apartmentNumber", primary_key: "apartmentNumber", name: "room_StudentFlats_apartmentNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "student", "advisor", column: "advisorNumber", primary_key: "advisorNumber", name: "Student_Advisor_advisorNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "student_flats", "lease", column: "leaseID", primary_key: "leaseNumber", name: "StudentFlats_Lease_leaseNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "vehicle", "parking_lot", column: "lotNumber", primary_key: "lotNumber", name: "Vehicle_ParkingLot_lotNumber_fk"
  add_foreign_key "vehicle", "student", column: "mUNum", primary_key: "mUNumber", name: "Vehicle_Student_mUNumber_fk"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<%= residence_staff.hallName %>` use `<%= residence_staff.hall.hallName %>` because `hallName` is an attribute of `hall`.

As an aside, ruby naming conventions favor snake case. `hallName` would be `hall_name` instead.

Comment: Ok I did that and now I am getting this error: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'residence_staffs.hall_id' in 'on clause': SELECT `residence_staffs`.* FROM `residence_staffs` INNER JOIN `halls` ON `halls`.`hallId` = `residence_staffs`.`hall_id` WHERE `residence_staffs`.`position` = 'manager'

Comment: I believe that is because of the naming conventions used in Rails.  You could override it, but it would probably be better to rename `hallId` to `hall_id` > Rails expects foreign keys in the database to have an _id suffix, and will map relations to those keys automatically if the names line up.

Comment: This line `belongs_to :hall, primary_key: 'hallId'` does not match your schema `t.string "hall", limit: 50, null: false` should be an integer named `hall_id`. You can test things out in `rails console` (`rails c`). It is wired up correctly when you can enter `ResidenceStaff.first.hall` without errors.